# Numpy array Regex sub

Tags: python, regex, numpy

I am sure it should be just one line but I am not able to figure out the best to do this:

```
import numpy as np
import re
arr = np.array(["AB", "AC", "XAB", "XAC", "AD"])
```

I want to add "X" in the beginning based on a regex match of "^A".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
print(np.array(list(map(lambda v: re.sub(r'^A','XA', v) ,arr))))
% outputs: ['XAB' 'XAC' 'XAB' 'XAC' 'XAD']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) I ended up using the regex pattern from @nu11p01n73R instead of "^A"

Comment: Using a list comprehension is shorter: `np.array([re.sub('^A','XA',a) for a in arr])`.  Does `arr` need to be an array, or return one?  This looks like a list of strings problem, not a `numpy` one.

Comment: Ohh I see. Yeah - it need not be a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sub` function in `re` module to substitute strings as

```
>>> import re
>>> str="ABC"
>>> re.sub('^(?=A)','X', str)
'XABC'
```

`^(?=A)` is lookahead assertion which matches start postition in anystring that begins with 'A'

Comment: Thanks. I combined your and Marcin's solution.

Comment: @KapilSharma glad to hear it worked :)