# Some regex doesn't work in numpy arrays

Tags: python, regex, numpy

I'm starting with:

```
vals 
Out[205]: array([['NA\xa0[1] (16.0\xa0to\xa0N/A)', '12.0\xa0[2]', 'NA\xa0[1]']], dtype=object)
```

then:

```
v = vals.astype('str')

v = np.char.replace(v,'\xa0' , ' ')                

v
Out[210]: 
array([['NA [1] (16.0 to N/A)', '12.0 [2]', 'NA [1]']],
```

and then:

```
v = np.char.replace(v,'\s*\[[0-9]+\]\s*' , '').tolist()

v
Out[212]: [['NA [1] (16.0 to N/A)', '12.0 [2]', 'NA [1]']]
```

The issue is this second replacement doesn't work while the first does. Regex seems to be ok - it should remove such `[1]` chars.

I've found later it's something with regex in Python and square brackets: `[2]` works `[0-9]` doesn't. How to deal with it?

Comment: `np.char.replace` does not seem to support regex.

Comment: Ah, so my approach is wrong? It replaces character only? What should I use in this case?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.replace.html#numpy.core.defchararray.replace

Comment: If you're using numpy, take this a step forward and use pandas, which extensively supports regex.

Comment: Not a perfect tip, but relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541279/numpy-array-regex-sub (closed and something a tiny bit different)

Comment: If you are working with variable-length strings, you should reconsider using `numpy` arrays. They aren't really built with that use-case in mind. Either maybe `pandas` or even just plain `list` objects would work better.

Comment: The `np.char` functions apply regular `str` methods to elements of an array (usually str dtype).  While convenient, they don't offer any real speed advantage over explicit iteration.  And as you must have found out, they don't work with object dtype.

Comment: Thanks for very good suggestions, especially for go into pandas. I've found my provisional solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

Found the temporary answer before using pandas. Just need to apply `re.sub` within a list.

```
[re.sub('\s*\[[0-9]+]\s*', '', x) for x in v[0]]
Out[240]: ['NA(16.0 to N/A)', '12.0', 'NA']
```

easy-peasy